# Getting Server languageserver.ccls failed to start: error, when ever I open cpp file inside neovim

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, neovim-qt

I get the following error:

```
Server languageserver.ccls failed to start: Launching server "languageserver.ccls" using command ccls failed.
```

I have installed coc-ccls, and I have pasted this below code inside cocconfig file,

```
{
      "languageserver": {
          "ccls": {
              "command": "ccls",
              "filetypes": [
                  "c",
                  "cpp",
                  "objc",
                  "objcpp"
              ],
              "rootPatterns": [
                  ".ccls",
                  "compile_commands.json",
                  ".vim/",
                  ".git/",
                  ".hg/"
              ],
              "initializationOptions": {
                  "cache": {
                      "directory": "/tmp/ccls"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Does running `ccls` manually works? (Did you install it?) Does `:message` show more details on what went wrong?

Comment: @statox No I'm new to neovim, I'm installed neovim, I added to path, then I installed `CocInstall coc-clsss`, I was following an article but when I opened cpp file inside neovim using `nvim .\filename.cpp ` I got that error.

Comment: @statox I'm trying to use neovim for C++ programming, Please help, If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Then you probably need to install `ccls`. On a debian based machine you can simply use `apt install ccls`, for other system you'll have to find the installation instructions.